# Workbox plugin not considering output.publicPath to load serviceworker file

Tags: webpack, workbox

I am using workbox-webpack-plugin with following configuration.

```
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      globDirectory: outputDir,
      globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js}'],
      swDest: path.join(outputDir, 'sw.js'),
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: new RegExp('cdn.test.com/'),
          handler: 'CacheFirst'
        }
      ]
    })
```

This builds correctly. But problem is for loading `sw.js` file. I have a custom path(https://test.com/custom/) rather direct to domain(https://test.com). After build, the path sw.js is trying to load is via https://test.com/sw.js rather https://test.com/custom/sw.js where my whole application build resides. And this is the path mentioned in my `output.publicPath` of webpack as well. How can I set that in Workbox plugin config? I am using `"3.0.0-beta.2"` version.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I need to register service worker in my application where I can mention the path.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/custom/sw.js').then(registration => {
      console.log('SW registered: ', registration);
    }).catch(registrationError => {
      console.log('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
    });
  });
}
```

resolved the problem